# Front usb ports won't respond, back ports do

Tags: usb

I'm not sure when, but my ubuntu machine stopped responding to front usb ports. Any device plugged into the rear of the machine work fine, but the front don't do anything. My phone won't even draw power when plugged into the front. I am using the ringtail experimental build, but they were working fine last night.

The lsusb command returns

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 040a:4066 Kodak Co. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f2:0841 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

if that helps... A lot of similar posts asked for that info, trying to save you guys asking.

Comment: USB ports dying is not uncommon.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's not the ports, I have more info now. It only seems to ignore the ports when I plug in a usb to mini usb. I'm thinking it might be a problem with that cable... The ports work if I leave that cable off... I'm running more tests.